# Facebook comment.create not firing on mobile - ios Safari and android browser

Tags: javascript, web-applications, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is making me crazy - I can't get the facebook comment.create event to fire on mobile devices (not that I tested work). login event is working fine (auth.authResponseChange)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'MYAPPID', // App ID
    channelUrl : '//WWW.MYAPPURL.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) { alert("1"); });
//  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {alert("1"); });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));


</script>


<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>


comments
<div class="fb-comments" data-notify="true" data-href="http://test/test.htm" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebook FB.Event.subscribe is not firing on mobile version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110749/facebook-fb-event-subscribe-is-not-firing-on-mobile-version)

Comment: this was opened on JUL-13 and the question in the link you provided was opened in OCT-13 (so the second one is duplicate) + check out the bug in FB... I opened it :)

Comment: You're right. I marked this one as a duplicate because the other question had an answer with reference to your reported bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that this is still an ongoing FB  [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/604681079553717)