# facebook FB.Event.subscribe is not firing on mobile version

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying create a small notifier thingy when a comment have been created for an advert. It works flawlessly on the desktop version, but on the mobile version the `FB.Event.subscribe` is not fired.

I have this code:

```
    <script>

         window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'XXXX'
          channelUrl : 'http://www.xxx.dk/channel.php',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true
        });


        FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',
           function (response) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://www.xxx.dk/notify.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: { aid: {$viewad.aid} },
                  success: function(data) { },
                  error: function(data) { }
                });
            });
      };  

      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
 </script>
```

both fbAsyncInit and FB.init is being fired correctly! If I put in alert("fired") I will get that alert, but not inside FB.Event.subscribe

channel.php contain this:

```
<?php
$cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$cache_expire);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
?>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can see it is the specific **comment.create** event that isn't fired.
**edge.create** works fine.

Comment: And it is only the mobile version of the comment box. Setting **mobile="false"** fixes the problem, but that's not good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebok comment.create not firing on mobile - ios Safari and android browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844268/facebok-comment-create-not-firing-on-mobile-ios-safari-and-android-browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the plugin

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/604681079553717

Damn.. FB are slow on fixing!